# Trigger an Appveyor build on particular commit

Tags: appveyor

What I require is a command that start a build of a certain commit on Appveyor with particular environment variables. From the guides, there is:

- From the build worker API: `Start-AppveyorBuild` which allows you to pass in environment variables but only lets you specify the branch, not the commit.
- From the REST API: `POST /api/builds` which allows you to choose the commit hash, but can't set any environment variables for the ensuing build.

What is available that allows me to do both? I am fine to use either the build worker API or the REST API (although REST is preferable so then I can run it anywhere).

Broader context is I want a build to kick off a separate build that will run a deployment script of the same commit (same branch not good enough - branch may have been updated). They need to be separate builds due to the fact that both the first and second build together take too long for Appveyor's 60 minute time limit. The environment variables are to "configure" the build so that it deploys rather than does the other stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this sample (and write to `team at appveyor.com` if you need us to increase timeout to 90 minutes)

```
$token = '<API_Token>'

$headers = @{
  "Authorization" = "Bearer $token"
  "Content-type" = "application/json"
}

$body = @{
    accountName="<Your_account>"
    projectSlug="<Your_project_slug>"
    branch="<Your_branch>"
    commitId="<Your_commit_id>"
}
$body = $body | ConvertTo-Json

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://ci.appveyor.com/api/builds' -Headers $headers  -Body $body -Method POST
```

Comment: Thank you that looks perfect (assuming it works). It appears that the docs https://www.appveyor.com/docs/api/projects-builds/ have split up their "definition" of the call into two examples, which I assumed were mutually exclusive. Are there docs anywhere that specify exactly all of the possible values in the body?

Comment: That's basically it. The only thing missed is `PullRequestId` (as described [here](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/api/projects-builds/#start-build-of-pull-request-github-only)). It cannot be used with `branch` and `commitId` because of obvious reasons. PR is GitHub only, but BitBucket and GitLab are coming this summer.
And again do not hesitate to ask for 90 minutes timeout :) We need your account name to increase.

Comment: From testing it appears that the `branch` key is necessary for this post (`commitId` alone is insufficient) due to the mechanics of appveyor using `git clone`. Is this correct? This is not directly related to the question, I'm just asking this out of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Using curl you can do using below, branch is not required and it gives an error if specifieid. Git commit is enough:

```
response=`curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ${APPVEYOR_TOKEN}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://ci.appveyor.com/api/builds --data-binary "{ accountName: '${accountName}', projectSlug: '${projectName}', commitId: '${commitId}' }"`
```